# How to organize the applications in django project

Tags: django

I getting started with Django. I want to build a work_manager website with the following content:

1. hour calculation - enter shifts per day and can view the hours per day, week and month.
2. shift for each week(maybe a month too) - view table for all the schedules of the employees.
3. salary calculation per employee for month.

And maybe in the future more things.

For start I have this DB structures:

[image]

Now, my question is what is the recommended way to organize the project?

I searched here and find some people the recommended **putting all in one app** because strong relations between the models can cause problems if you split into several apps.

And some other people recommended **to split it** that each I can explain each app with one sentence (like I did here up).

So, what is the best practice for that? If to split so how to arrange the models?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

it depend on you requirement.
if you want to reuse this app to some other project. then splitting is very good idea.
splitting a project in multiple app are very easy to maintain. if you want to add some more functionality to your app it will be easy for you. only draw back i see in splitting multiple app is it increase burden of importing models and other stuff.

other hand if you put every thing in one app it will also work very well. but it will be tough to maintain and scale n future.

my suggestion is to split app as many as possible.

Comment: How would you recommend splitting the project in my specific case? Which models in which app and what are their connections?